# Could airport security devices detect differences between printed and written documents?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, thermal-radiation, x-rays

If airport security scanners of any kind (xray, thermal, whatever else they use) looked at two items:

- A printed paper textbook
- The same printed paper textbook into which we have inserted a regular folded US letter-sized paper with something written on it with a pencil, pen, marker, etc.

Could the security be able to detect the difference between the two?

Comment: Are you planning on trying to smuggle something through airport security?

Comment: Hope you're using a proxy.

Comment: The same answer here applies: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112726/could-airport-security-possibly-distinguish-gold-and-silver-coins-from-other-coi Just plug in different numbers. And don't smuggle illegal things.

Comment: If they are using a laser system they possibly could.  I doubt they would because it'd be expensive, huge, and could possibly kill people.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I don't think the plebs aka 'airport security staff' are too concerned with hand-written notes :)

Comment: @JamalS: OP asked 2 questions about getting things through airport security (this being the second). My comment was based on that aspect, not this particular question.

Answer (score 3):

No, it would look exactly the same as far as the x-ray is concerned.

Think x-ray passing through paper and ink.

Thermal?

Answer (score 3):

Paper is paper. Airport security won't find a piece of hand-written paper inside  a book because they aren't looking for it. They are almost exclusively concerned with weapons, and paper isn't a weapon. They don't even want to find things like narcotics - not their job and it requires lots of police paperwork. Similarly, they are spectacularly uninterested in the contents of your computer.

Now, that's security getting on the plane. If you are talking about Customs and Immigration after you get off the plane, that's a different story. If you have come to the attention of C&I, the folded paper will be of interest and will be read. If it's homework on the textbook topic, no problem. If it's building plans to a national monument you should expect to miss your connecting flight.